# Create a TXT File in SD Card and write into it in android not working

Tags: android, file, android-studio, android-sdcard

```
String fileName = "sample";
try {
     final File f= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
     FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
     fo.write(code.getBytes());
     fo.close();
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I need to copy a String named `code` to my file named `sample`.

If I do this, I  don't get any errors. However, if use my phone and debug into my SD card, no File is created. Can anyone please tell me what I have done wrong??

Comment: `if use my connected android phone as emulator `. ???? How does one do that?

Comment: `and look into my sdcard , no file is created`. Indeed. It will not have been created on the micro SD card but on external memory of the phone.

Comment: `I dont get any errors. ` You should get a Toast! Which one?

Comment: USB Debbuging in my phone. The try toast appears. @greenapps

Comment: `String fileName = "sample";` and `"Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'"`. You can prevent such confusing messages by not hard coding them but to use `file.getName()` or `file.getAbsolutePath()`. With the last one you know where you have to look exactly.

Comment: So where did you look? And how? With which file explorer app on your device?

Comment: I conncted my phone to pc and looked with My comp explorer for USB @greenapps

Comment: Wrong. Use a file explorer app on your device.

Comment: Its working. Thank you!!! May I know why  it is like this? like why i dont get in my pc directory? @greenapps

Answer (score 1):

You can change file object

```
File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS+"/myfile.txt");
```